# Are conditional expressions in C++ always of bool type?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, language-lawyer, c++03

In C conditional-oriented operators evaluate to either `1` or `0` of type `int` (even if it does have dedicated `_Bool` type). Referring to [C11 N1570 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> #### C11 §6.5.8/6 *Relational operators*
>
> Each of the operators `<` (less than), `>` (greater than), `<=` (less than
>   or equal to), and `>=` (greater than or equal to) shall yield 1 if the
>   specified relation is true and 0 if it is false.<sup>107)</sup> The result has
>   type `int`.
>
> #### C11 §6.5.9/3 *Equality operators*
>
> The `==` (equal to) and `!=` (not equal to) operators are analogous to the
>   relational operators except for their lower precedence.<sup>108)</sup> Each of
>   the operators yields 1 if the specified relation is true and 0 if it
>   is false. The result has type `int`. For any pair of operands, exactly
>   one of the relations is true.
>
> #### C11 6.5.13/3 *Logical AND operator*
>
> The `&&` operator shall yield 1 if both of its operands compare unequal
>   to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type `int`.
>
> #### C11 6.5.14/3 *Logical OR operator*
>
> The `||` operator shall yield 1 if either of its operands compare
>   unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type `int`.

As I checked C++ seems to be different in this matter, as in following example (see http://ideone.com/u3NxfW):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main() {
    double x = 10.0;

    std::cout << typeid(x <= 10.0).name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

outputs `b`, which as I guess indicates `bool` type. Does C++ guarantee that all of these operators always evaluate to `bool` type (in contrast to C)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Contrary to C, in C++, relational operators, equality operators and logical operators (logical AND, logical OR and logical negation) all yield a value of type `bool`.

For example:

> (C++11, 5.9p1 Relational operators) "[...] The type of the result is bool."

**EDIT:** for the sake of completeness, all the operators listed above can be overloaded and thus the resulting type can be changed. See Arne Vogel answer for real life [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28094135/1119701).

Comment: Assuming they have not been overridden.

Comment: Ah, "nitpicker's corner" is back :)

Comment: @Bulletmagnet It's more than a nit, because an awful lot of comparisons in C++ will involve user defined operators, which can (but shouldn't) return any type.

Answer (score 14):

No, because of operator overloading. This has been mentioned before, but I can give the real life example of [expression templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates). The idea, generally, is to allow writing "lazy" expressions (that is, really, function objects or [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)s) with syntax that is very similar to the normal, eager use of logical operators. Typically, many other operators, in particular arithmetic operators are also, overloaded.

For instance, one design goal of Boost.Lambda was to simplify the use of algorithms:

```
std::string str;
// ...
std:.string::iterator firstA = std::find_if(str.begin(), str.end(), _1 == 'a' || _1 == 'A');
```

Previously, in "pure" C++98, it was generally necessary to write numerous named functions or function objects before many standard algorithms could be used effectively.

Since C++11, Boost.Lambda is not as useful any more since lambda expressions have been added to the core language. There are still numerous EDSLs (embedded domain-specific languages) where C++11 lambdas cannot replace expression templates though, e.g. you may want to generate SQL command strings directly from a C++ EDSL in a way similar to LINQ in .NET, but as a portable library solution. Another example: the [VexCL](https://ddemidov.github.io/vexcl/) library uses expression templates to generate GPU kernels.

This is probably the only legitimate use of non-bool return types for overloaded logical operators, but it's not generally considered esoteric.